# How to make a 'git diff branch1...branch2' in Intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, compare, diff

Intellij has a great way of presenting the diff between two git branches with the [Compare tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/merging-deleting-and-comparing-branches.html).

However, this seems to correspond to a

```
git diff branch1..branch2
```

Is there a way to perform

```
git diff branch1...branch2
```

(with three dots)

Comment: I just typed both options my console and saw no difference? What are you expecting as a result? Are you expecting the same output as github's compare tool, which uses the `...`?

Comment: @bitoiu: as a special case, `git diff` treats the three-dot syntax as meaning: find the merge base of the two branches listed, and then diff that commit against the second commit listed.  (I have no idea whether Intellj has a way to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

I've read the docs on IntelliJ, searched the options on the VCS and found nothing to specify options to the diff.

From reading up the documentation on `diff` I can only suggest for you navigate to the merge-base, checkout another branch and do the `diff`, like:

Assuming:

- `branch1` is the mainline
- `branch2` was branched off branch1
- commit `abc123` is the merge-base of `branch1` and `branch2`

Do:

```
git checkout abc123
git checkout -b branch1-temp
```

Then go to IntelliJ and compare those two branches. Otherwise just use the command-line `...` notation.

Comment: this is not really want I wanted but thanks for the suggested workaround

Comment: It's a contrived solution, since I don't see a way to do what you want unless you open an issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BVersion+Control.+Git%7D+ . They are usually very quick with new features, extremely quick.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to see changes in Intellij Idea as would be seen in three-dot git diff.

#### Why three-dot diff

I will describe my case when I needed three-dot diff. There was large pull request on github that I needed to inspect. Branch `F(eature)` was branched out of `M(aster)`, some changes were made to both, then some changes from `M(aster)` were already merged into `F(eature)`. Now after more changes I want to merge `F(eature)` into `M(aster)`.

`F -> M
|    |
*    *
|    |
*    *
|\   |
| \  |
|  \ |
*    * <- X
|    |
*    *
 \   |
  \  |
   \ |
     * <- P`

#### Solution

1. Create three-dot diff and dump it to file from command line

`git diff master...feature > diff`

2. Checkout commit X
3. In Idea, open the Apply patch dialog and choose the file created at step 1

Now you will see Apply patch dialog with changes similar to those you would see in github pull request

#### Drawbacks

You cannot change anything in branch `F(eature)`

You cannot see who committed changes

You cannot compile/run until you apply the patch

Answer (score 0):

I've found a method that's ok but not perfect.

Right click on the project -> Git -> Compare With...

Then on the File Revisions dialog choose the top-most commit that's not part of this branch. That can be hard to determine, but there's a good chance it's the first one by another author. For example, if this were the File Revisions history:

```
d4c3af  today         Craig
c3af21  today         Craig
b2af3a  yesterday     Bob
a1af73  two days ago  Alice
```

and if I knew I was reviewing Craig's branch, I'd pick Bob's commit. Then IntelliJ gives me a diff for just changes in Craig's branch.